# Implementing ResNet50 for custom object detection of a single class

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, computer-vision, object-detection

I want to implement the ResNet50 architecture for custom object detection of a single class. I have two folders in my dataset, one containing the images and the other containing the annotations that are stored as .txt files. I have tried using detecto but it requires the annotations to be .xml files. I have also tried the Tensorflow and PyTorch models of ResNet50, but they don't accept the annotations as .txt files. I require the annotations to be in .txt files. Can you please tell me how to make the ResNet50 model for custom object detection in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

- The SSD-ResNet50 accepts only annotations in `.xml` format only. As they are pre-trained models you have sent the inputs in the desired format only.
- To implement the object-detection with annotations in the `.txt.` format you have use the Faster-RCNN models which accepts annotations in the `.txt` format. Thank You!